# Get on sale products for Woocommerce product category archives using a Get request

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode, product

I want to be able to show only products on sale for any of the categories I have on my website. I have seen that you can use [Woocommerce shortcodes](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/).

However my Wordpress theme is dynamic (it runs for all product categories) and I can't really create one page using a shortcode for each of the product categories (some categories are created "on the go" when I add new products).

Is there any way I can simply have a query string to return the category with only on sale products?

For example: `https://www.website.com/clothing/dresses?on_sale=true`

---EDIT:---

I am not using shortcodes, just want a simple solution for the query parameter.

Forgot to mention that on my case I always have values on the "_regular_price" and "_sale_price" regardless if is on sale or not. Here are the examples:

Product **ON SALE** (prices are different):
[image]

Product **NOT** on sale (prices are the same):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter the main query via the [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) filter.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'modify_query_show_on_sale_products' );

function modify_query_show_on_sale_products( $query ) {

    if( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->query_vars['wc_query'] == 'product_query' ) {

        $query->set('meta_key', '_sale_price');
        $query->set('meta_value', '0');
        $query->set('meta_compare', '>=');
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you so much Andrew! However I forgot to mention that for our case a product on sale means that _sale_price is different from a _regular_price (I have edited my question with some extra information). How would I adapt the query to solve it?

Comment: You should remove the on sale price completely otherwise it will cause issues with WooCommerce and related plugins thinking the product is still on sale.